# PHP - Convert information supplied in a string format to an array format

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string

```
$attribute_options_string = "Spice (Very Hot/3, Hot/2, Medium/1) | Size(Small,Medium,Large)";

$attribute_options_array = array(
 'spice' => array(
    'very hot' =>3,
     'hot' => 2,
     'medium' => 1
 ),
    'size' => array(
        'small',
        'medium',
        'large'
    )
);
```

I am trying to write a function that converts the string format to the array format.

Comment: Okay. What have you tried? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: explode on pipe, loop, explode on comma, loop, explode on slash if needed, profit

Comment: @tim not quite that simple, you also have to extract the option name (Spice/Size)

Comment: @Nick "explode on slash if needed" :-)

Comment: @tim sorry, I shouldn't have said `Spice/Size`, I was referring to extracting the value at the beginning of the strings after exploding on pipe.

Comment: missed exploding brackets (or just the `(` ) I guess.

Comment: Exploding by pipe was the easy part. Extracting the Spice/Size and the options within the () needed regex and that is what I was struggling with. Thanks Nick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was succinctly described by @tim in the comments, you just need to:

> explode on pipe, loop, explode on comma, loop, explode on slash if needed

It's not quite that simple as you need to extract the option name, and since you seem to have variable spacing in your strings it's safer to use `preg_split` rather than `explode`. Based on your sample data, this will work:

```
$attribute_options_string = "Spice (Very Hot/3, Hot/2, Medium/1) | Size(Small,Medium,Large)";
$attribute_options_array = array();
$attributes = preg_split('/\s*\|\s*/', $attribute_options_string);
foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
    preg_match('/\s*(\w+)\s*\(([^)]+)/', $attribute, $matches);
    $attribute_name = strtolower($matches[1]);
    $options = preg_split('/\s*,\s*/', $matches[2]);
    foreach ($options as $option) {
        if (strpos($option, '/') !== false) {
            list($option_name, $option_value) = preg_split('#\s*/\s*#', $option);
            $attribute_options_array[$attribute_name][strtolower($option_name)] = $option_value;
        }
        else {
            $attribute_options_array[$attribute_name][] = strtolower($option);
        }
    }
}
var_export($attribute_options_array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'spice' => array (
    'very hot' => '3',
    'hot' => '2',
    'medium' => '1',
  ),
  'size' => array (
    0 => 'small',
    1 => 'medium',
    2 => 'large', 
  ), 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/PfaMC)